# Angular 6, how to update angular input field while looping?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-forms

I am trying to generate dynamic number of `mat-form-field` inside a html page.

I have the following data in component file:

```
data = [{
    'name': 'XYZ',
    'id': 1,
    'accNo': 123
  },
  {
    'name': 'ABC',
    'id': 2,
    'accNo': 456
  },
  {
    'name': 'PQR',
    'id': 3,
    'accNo': 567
  }
  ]
```

And in html, I am looping as follows:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="deposit-box" *ngFor="let c of data">
        <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Name:</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" 
        [(ngModel)]=c.name>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am facing problem in updating the value in `input` tag. only the first 
`mat-form-field` is getting the value.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7a7add

Please help me.

Currently I am getting output as:

[image]

Comment: Hi Anil. Could you please update if any of these answers helped you fix your issue. If you did get an answer, please also consider marking the most relevant answer as a solution to close the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ngFor` inside the `mat-form`

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <div *ngFor="let c of data">  
        <mat-label>Name:</mat-label>
        <input placeholder="Placeholder" [(ngModel)]=c.name>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikcs8v?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: you were missing couple of material modules in the main modules. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apme7d?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Check @Justcode answer. those were the missing modules.

Comment: @Anil, you are also missing the Theme CSS. Check out my answer for more.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are missing two imports in module, you could have done this easily by checking your console,

Change your imports to

```
import {MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatIcon,MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

I added `MatInputModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` and it works as expected now.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtldfb)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your implementation:

Add the following modules to the `imports` array of your `AppModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatIcon, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You were missing `MatInputModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule`.

Also, add a name attribute to your `input` tag and wrap `c.name` in quotes:

```
<input 
  matInput 
  placeholder="Placeholder" 
  [(ngModel)]="c.name"
  name="name">
```

Finally, add this to your styles.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcrosb?file=src%2Fstyles.css) for your ref.

---

**PS:** For the sake of this answer, I'm importing everything related to Angular Material from `@angular/material`. Ideally, each module should be imported from a deeper path. For eg:

```
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
```

Answer (score -1):

use `ngfor` instead of `<mat-form-field>`

`<mat-form-field>` is wrapper component for text styling. Here is an example of `ngFor` to loop over an array [ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data)